# UserManager doesn't recover stored Roles from user ( Identity 2.1 ASP MVC 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, user-roles

The roles stored in the database are not recovered by UserManager.GetRoles(userId);

I have use Identity before and never happend this... don't know what I have done this time or what's happening...

How I create user and his role:

```
var result = manager.Create(applicationUser, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
   var userRegistered = manager.FindByName(applicationUser.UserName);

   var roleResult = manager.AddToRole(userRegistered.Id, model.Rol);

   if(roleResult.Succeeded){return true;}
}
```

This return true and data store on db tables ( user, and userRole) but..

When I login I can't access to actions... with role authorization...

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
  public ActionResult Delete(string id)
```

On debug I have checked that user have no items on Roles list !!!

Posts I've seen haven't helped me solve the problem , any idea why it does not work ?

Im working with Identity 2.1 ASP MVC 5 on VS 2013comm

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: What is the value of `model.Rol`?

Comment: the string name of the rol that I'm adding to the user. in this case take "Admin"

Comment: Did you re-login the user after adding the roles?

Comment: Is the record about the role created in the database?

Comment: sure  both ;) @trailmax

Comment: Sounds like your login procedure does not pick up roles to store into the cookie. Can you show your login methods?

Comment: @trailmax I didn't code anything for that propose :/ , I'm using default framework login system and actions

Comment: refere to this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352732/usermanager-getroles-doesnt-work-after-extending-the-identityuserrole-in-mvc-5/32353062#32353062