# Add roles to asp.net mvc code template by only using SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am experimenting with the asp.net MVC code template. I want to add roles to this simple website. I know this can be done via code, but for a better understanding of the database structure I would like to add my roles manualy via SQL scripts. To do this I have tried the following:

I first runned the website and via the standard MVC register-form, I added a user name 'registeredUser'.

Next I connected a role to the 'registeredUser' with the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @roleId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
DECLARE @userId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT id FROM AspNetUsers WHERE    
UserName= 'registeredUser')
INSERT INTO AspNetRoles (Id, Name) VALUES (@roleId, 'Administrator')
INSERT INTO AspNetUserRoles (RoleId, UserId) VALUES(@roleId, @userId)
```

Then I changed the autorization check of the registration method so that only a user with the role Administrator is allowed to view the registration page:

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
  public ActionResult Register()
  {
      return View();
  }
```

After doing this I would expect that only the user named 'registeredUser' would be able to access the registration page. But when I login as 'registeredUser' I cannot navigate to the registration page. When I add the role via code, everything works fine:

```
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var man = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        var user = man.FindByName("registeredUser);
        man.AddToRole(user.Id, "Administrator");
        context.SaveChanges();
```

But I want to add this via SQL, not via c# code. So what am I missing? How can I add a role by using only SQL-scripts? Am I missing an INSERT or is there some extra script that I need to add?

Thx

Comment: check values in discriminator column in db and also query :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352732/usermanager-getroles-doesnt-work-after-extending-the-identityuserrole-in-mvc-5/32353062#32353062

Comment: Run SQL profiler on the database while adding via code to see the SQL that executes.

Comment: Thx, apparently my problems where cause by case sensitivity issues. The GUID that i added via the SQL script had a different casing than the ones added by entity framework. Changing the casing of my GUID solved the problem.